# Marquee text if it is too long

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have an if/else statement setup, However my object `mediaTitle` often is over 20 characters long - example `Caught Up In You (Album Version)`.
How am I able to do a marquee if the text is over 20 characters long?

I have tried

```
if ( mediaState === "off") {    
  $("#title").html( '&nbsp;' );    
} else {
  $("#title").html('<marquee>' + mediaTitle + '</marquee>');
}
```

and I have tried this

```
var count = "19";

} else if (mediaTitle > count) {
  $("#title").html('<marquee>' + mediaTitle + '</marquee>');
}
```

When doing this the marquee only shows the first 5 characters then it starts over.

Comment: Yes, but for some reason the marquee only moves over about 5 characters and restarts.

Comment: yes, your code is perfect, its something else in my project!

Comment: I can suggest that you don't need this rows anymore: `if ( mediaState === "off") {    
  $("#title").html( '&nbsp;' );    
} else {
  $("#title").html('<marquee>' + mediaTitle + '</marquee>');
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compare `mediaTitle.length` with `count`, and if `mediaTitle.length > count`, insert the marquee:

```js
var mediaTitle = 'This example is longer than 20 characters';
var count = 20;


if (mediaTitle.length > count) {
  $("#title").html('<marquee>' + mediaTitle + '</marquee>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="title"></div>
```